# Return 2 params into another method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I interpret several strings with different methods, but they all return two values in the same format. I would like to then pass these two values directly into another method. Is this possible? I keep getting an error saying `"Expecting 2 params, got 1"`

```
def step1 (text)
  return "test1", "test2"
end

def step2 (val1, val2)
   do stuff...
end

step2 (step1 "this is a string")
```

Comment: Use of the `return` keyword is redundant in Ruby if it's the last line of a method, as that's what's returned by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `*` to destructure, an option:

```
step2(*step1("this is a string")) # Note required parens around step1 param
```

Returning multiple params like this is syntactic sugar; you're actually returning an array.

If you're trying to build a DSL you might want to consider going a different way.

If you're just working on a non-DSL-ish API I'd probably change method signatures and destructure the array inside `step1`, e.g., `val1, val2 = arg1` and skip some complexity.

Comment: I'd always seen that referred to as [splat arguments](http://endofline.wordpress.com/2011/01/21/the-strange-ruby-splat/), where "destructuring" is used on assignment: `a, *b = step2(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you are passing single parameter ,You can do this as follows:

```
def step1 (text)
  return "step 1 called.."
end

def step2 (val1, val2)
   return "step 2 called.."
end

step2(method(:step1),"this is a string")
```

Comment: Whoa, what? That's a very different thing.

Comment: I think he want to call one method as a parameter of other method and error is because wrong no of argument pass.

Comment: OP is saying they want to return multiple values from one method, and use them as arguments to another, which is possible via destructuring. Passing in one as a method is very different, and isn't helpful unless it's actually called in the method-e.g., in your example the (single) return value of `step1` is completely ignored. Not saying you can't modify your example to actually work, but it's a pretty convoluted approach IMO.